# Why does Qt needs allocate of child objects in the Heap?

Tags: qt

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget { public:
    MyWidget( QWidget *parent=0, const char *name=0 ); };


MyWidget::MyWidget( QWidget *parent, const char *name )
        : QWidget( parent, name ) {
    QPushButton *quit = new QPushButton( "Quit", this, "quit" );
    quit->setGeometry( 62, 40, 75, 30 );
    quit->setFont( QFont( "Times", 18, QFont::Bold ) ); 
}
```

In the above code `quit` is allocated in Heap and it is necessary since it is child of MyWidget

Why does Qt needs allocate of child objects in the Heap?

Comment: If I guess what you mean, your question seems daft, so I assume I am wrong as to your meaning, so you should alliterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea here is that Qt has it's own internal reference counting on most objects and if you pass them around, uses copy-on-write etc.

Could you be more specific in your question?

Comment: Implicitly shared objects do **internal** heap allocation for the PIMPL data, but that's an implementation detail. A common case where you can have stack-only reference-counted objects is passing anything implicitly shared via a sent event or a directly connected signal. Say, when you pass a `QString` to a slot using a direct connection. None of the string instances live on the heap. The PIMPL lives on the heap - but again, that's not what the question was about.

Comment: If they're on the heap, and child objects notify parents of their deletion, then you have the option to delete them fairly arbitrarily.

Answer (score 5):

In your example quit doesn't have to be heap allocated.

This code compiles and executes fine:

```
struct MyWidget : QWidget 
{
    QPushButton quit;

    MyWidget()
    {
        quit.setGeometry( 62, 40, 75, 30 );
        quit.setFont( QFont( "Times", 18, QFont::Bold ) );
    }
};
```

Comment: It also works if you add MyWidget as parent to the quit button (which is more interesting, I thinks). The button is destroyed before MyWidget and thus is de-parented before MyWidget is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, I think it mostly boils down to tradition and example, with a little bit of header-dependency thrown in.

The alternative, of course, is to declare `quit` as a member variable of `MyWidget`.  If you do this, then you would need to include the header file for `QPushButton` where `MyWidget` is declared, instead of in the implementation file.  The example you gave also relies on the parent-relationship of `QObject`s to keep track of the memory for the button, and delete it on destruction, so it doesn't need to be specified as a member in the class.

I'm pretty sure you could change to stack allocation if you really wanted to.

Answer (score -1):

What other options are there? From the stack? How would Qt know when to allocate from stack and when from the heap? Things allocated from the stack will be gone as soon as the current function returns, so the lifetime of the object could be much shorter than the usage time. Imagine adding a node to a tree. The node will be used long after the current function has returned. This would lead to access to random memory, segmentation faults, core dumps, etc.

Comment: You could have them as value members in another widget class, to avoid allocating many small objects all over the heap.

Comment: How would Qt know what you did when it starts to clean up memory in the destructor?

Comment: Member objects are destroyed first, so they un-parent themselves from their parent. Then the parent is destroyed. No problem at all. (This works, it's how I've done many times. Just be careful with using boost::shared_ptr and everything will be fine.)